# Dynamic Rendering of tiles as per custom selected options

Tags: openstreetmap, style

Cartida is one of the best Customize map providers.

```
https://www.cartida.com/global/map/
```

On Cartida, you can choose, whatever color of roads you want, whatever building color you want and so many other features. So, on each change of option, they call to a service, something like

```
https://maps.cartida.com/cartida/map?style=cartida&width=1205&height=850&bbox=8262171.608849932,3689647.5481946995,8292984.162073471,3711382.544244499&webmerclevel=12&boost=1&scalefactor=1.8179293857353394&colors=water:0x9BBCD9|land:0xffffff|objects:0x7a1f1f|buildings:0xffffff|background:0xFFFFFF&show=roads,road_details,water,landuse
```

How can I make a customizable map like this for my own area of interest? Let's say I have osm data for a city, and want to create a webapp that can provide such customization for layer on/off or color change etc.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html).

Comment: So, that is done throght Mapserver?

Comment: That's what you asked for with the MapServer tag.

Comment: Is there anny other way that you can suggest?

Comment: Use some other server software. It would require something similar.

Comment: it looks like you can contact Cartida directly for help with their product: https://www.cartida.com/global/help